# Attaching taxonomy data to taxonomy with wp_insert_post

Tags: taxonomy, post-meta, user-registration, wp-insert-post, customization

By `WP User Frontend` I create a registeration form with some checkboxes, and use `wp_insert_post` and `update_user_meta` for create a new post (post type pavilion) on user registration.
I want when checked a checkbox and submit registration form, publish a new post with a taxonomy. For example: I checked `cat` and submit form, then create a new post on pavalion with taxonomy `Cats` automatically. Checkboxes HTML source is:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" class="wpuf_my_pet_1153" name="my_pet[]" value="cat" checked="checked" />cat</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="wpuf_my_pet_1153" name="my_pet[]" value="dog" checked="checked" />dog</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="wpuf_my_pet_1153" name="my_pet[]" value="hamster" />hamster</label>
```

and my function code is:

```
function create_new_user_posts($user_id){
$userinfo = get_userdata($user_id);

    if (!$user_id>0)
            return;

    $my_bio_post = array(
         'post_title' => $userinfo->display_name,
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'post_type' =>  'pavilion',
         'post_author' => $user_id,

    );

    $bio = wp_insert_post( $my_bio_post );

    update_user_meta($user_id,'_bio_post',$bio);
}
```

Any idea?